# DataSet - Handing Null exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello I have this code but now I would like to handle DBnull exception but as I found so far the DataSet doesnt contain != operand.

May someone help me solve this null exception?

Thanks in advance

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT logo FROM firma WHERE id = 1", spojeni));

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

if (dataSet != DBNull.Value)
{
    if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
        data = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"]);
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try dataset != null

Comment: @Ankit `dataSet` won't never be null, because it's already initialized with a new instance before. We don't need any check here.

Comment: Please specify at which line you get the null exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking `DataSet` `DbNull` is not required as it can't ever be.

```
if (dataSet != DBNull.Value)//Not required
```

Then use `IsNull` method of `DataRow` to check against null.

To make your code much safe and clear I'll write it down as following

```
if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Datarow row = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];
    if(!row.IsNull("logo"))
    {
        Byte[] data = (Byte[])row["logo"];
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
    }
    else
    {
        //logo is null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A DataSet is never DBNull. But, the values within the dataset can be DBNull. You should check for DBNull on the value instead:

```
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
        object o = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"]
        if (! DBNull.Value.Equals(o)) {
            data = (Byte[])();
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
        } else {
            throw new NoLogoImageFoundException("Please remember to upload the logo");
        }
    }
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx for more info on `DBNull`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"].ToString()!= null )
    {
        Byte[] data = new Byte[0];
        data = (Byte[])(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["logo"]);
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);
    }
```